# iOS how white is a color

Tags: ios, colors, uicolor

So I have a color I've created and I'm trying to return a value of how white it is...

```
color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:188/255.f green:50/255.f blue:219/255.f alpha:1];
```

I can return the values of Hue, Saturation, Brightness using this method:

```
[color1 getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha];
```

It works great and I get all kinds of float values

But when I try to use Apple's "GetWhite" method the value returned is always 0.00000 no matter which color I input.

```
[color1 getWhite:&white alpha:&alpha];
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to convert the color to greyscale first? If so how do I do this? Is there and easier way to detect how white something is... just averaging the red/green/blue values then dividing by 255? Thanks!

**(*Also my reputation isn't high enough to add the tag "getWhite" to this, can somebody create it... When I googled for an answer for this nothing came up... maybe creating that tag will help others in need.)**

Comment: Does `getWhite` return `YES` or `NO` in your case?

Comment: a tag getWithe is a bad idea, what the hell you have thougt? It should be "color" or "color model"  "color computaions". The next one might demand a tag for how blue is my color

Comment: (It likely doesn't really return 0.0; check for an implicit conversion taking place.)

Comment: The float "white" returns 0.00000

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Well, sure, as does this: `float white = NO;`. (But no is not 0.0)

Comment: So how do I make it so the color can be converted? Or how do I determine how white a color is?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Tag denied. I edited the (now reverted) title to make it "more searchable". If you want it as such, I suggest changing the title as appropriate.

Comment: Why can't we have a tag for the function I am having issues with? Will it not help users?

Comment: No, it will not.  We do not need a tag for every single function under the sun.  You were also misusing [tag:white], which is not about the color at all.

Comment: Can you please offer me some insight about what the function is about then instead of just telling me why I'm wrong... people on this website are ridiculous.. all you can do is strut around looking down on everyone.

Comment: Is the tag going to do more harm than it does benefit?

Answer (score 2):

Your question indicates that you may not understand the purpose of getWhite. From the docs:

> If the color is in a compatible color space, the color is converted into grayscale format...

So the purpose of this function is to get the color value in grayscale. If you describe your purpose for getting this value, we may be able to help you in more detail.

That said, if this is really the function you want to use, you should test the return value of getWhite as well. The docs mention this about the return value:

> YES if the color could be converted, NO otherwise.

Comment: What is the "compatible color space"? How can I make the color compatible or is there a function to determine how white a color is that isn't in the compatible color space?